# How do I create a list of links that are hidden so when I hover over the main link all the other links show up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a list of links so when I hover over the top one the rest of the links show up. If this question has already answered point me to it. I have searched and couldn't find it. Sort of like when I hover over the links on  [this website](http://ahs.auburn.k12.ma.us/overview/classroom.phtml?sessionid=794eb6ac636d068ff2e2c2c15039ae03) more links show up underneath it.

Comment: Start here: http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery's [hover](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp), [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods.

Comment: Please don't just link to other sites as an answer, and I would suggest that you avoid W3Schools links altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jquery:

```
<a class='mainlink'>main Link</a>
<a class='sublink'>SubLink</a>
<a class='sublink'>Sublink</a>
```

javascript:

```
$('.mainLink').hover(
    function(){
        $('.sublink').show();
    },
    function(){
        $('.sublink').hide();
    });
```

But, instead of just pasting this, I would definitely read the tutorial by Jason P.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about nested cascaded Menus. **[This](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)** Tutorial will help you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

`<ul id="yourid1"><li>content</li><li>content</li></ul>`

CSS:

```
ul#yourid1 { height: -insert-height-of-one-li }
ul#yourid1:hover { height: -insert-full-height }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have two `<span>` or `<div>` and insert the main link in the first one and make it visible and make the other links display none and inside the second.

```
('MAIN LINK SPAN OR DIV').hover(
  function () {
    $("CHILD LINKS SPAN OR DIV").show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $("CHILD LINKS SPAN OR DIV").hide();
  }
);
```